# Primary key auto generated

Tags: jpa

I want to get the generated primary key after the persist of an entity.
Is there a solution with JPA?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The generated primary key is available after you flush your entity.

```
em.persist(myEntity);
em.flush();
return myEntity.getId();
```

or just return the entity (it will have the id after the transaction ends)

Comment: It works well now (return myEntity.getId();)
thank you very much.